# What's the difference between blank activity and basic activity in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-activity

I was learning android development recently, when I read some tutorials that said New a Empty Activity, but I can not find the Empty Activity. I only find the Blank Activity and Basic Activity. I want to know:

1. Which one is the same as the Empty Activity?
2. What's the difference between blank activity and basic activity in Android studio?

Comment: if you are beginner than use **Empty Activity** bcoz it improve your Android knowledge ......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Empty activity :** It has just the white screen and nothing  else.

**Basic activity :** It has some ready made contents (like action bar ) etc. you can see there will be `activity_content.xml` gets generated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

1.) Blank Activity is the same as Empty Activity.

2.)
Blank Activity is the simplest activity which you can create.

Basic Activity is more advanced than Empty/Blank Activity because have toolbar and one button (FAB).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Here is a screenshot from an older version of Android Studio] (older version of Android Studio, precise version unknown).

[image: Here is a screenshot from the latest version] 
(current version as of this writing, version 3.0.1).

Based on these screenshots, it appears that a Blank Activity has been renamed to a Basic Activity. Presumably to prevent confusion between the Blank/Basic activity and the Empty activity, the difference between which was explained by @Vivek_Neel's answer.

This seems to contradict the answer given by @koliczyna, because Blank is the same as Basic, and **not** the same as empty as they claim.

Answer (score 2):

**Empty activity** is the most elementary activity that we have in android. It is like a blank screen, whereas a **blank activity** has some extra features like the app bar and a floating action button.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose Blank Activity then you will have the option of having the activity use a Fragment. Also, Android Studio will automatically create two layout files for the activity, three if you choose the Fragment option, and also a menu resource file.

If you choose Empty Activity then you get to choose whether or not you want Android Studio to generate a layout file for the activity. If you choose the layout file option Android Studio will create one layout file, as opposed to two layout files in case of Blank Activity, and no menu resource file. Also, the layout file is much simpler and does not contain things like: Coordinator Layout, Floating Action Button, etc., whereas the layout file for Blank Activity contains these items, assuming you are using the latest version of Android Studio.